# Matplotlib - Add labels aligned to bottom of axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add labels to vertical lines on my chart (The magenta line in this case - 'TEXT TO GO HERE').

The problem is I don't know the minimum value of the Y axis as the axis is automatic and the text() function requires an x and y value.

I want to either be able to align the text to the bottom of the plot, or, find the minimum Y axis value (in this example it seems matplotlib is getting the minimum axis value and rounding it down by the major axis value)

I am currently trying to do this with text()

The vertical lines are created with axvline()

Screenshot to show what i'm trying to do below;

(Note the text on the image was added in my screen capture software to show where I want the text to appear)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a blended transform:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(
    ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

ax.plot(range(50))
ax.axvline(20)

ax.text(20, 0.05, 'test', transform=trans, rotation='vertical', ha='right')
```

[transform tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)

Comment: The problem is that I need a mix of the two systems as the X value is a date. The Y value I want to be just above the x axis, i.e. just above 1.5840 but even transforming a (0,0) back it doesnt give me the 1.5840. I tried both standard and inverse transforms.

Comment: @zio what you describe is exactly what this code does, the x is given in data units, and y is given in axis units ([0, 1])