# Add an extra information in a python plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose we have a figure with three plots in it for three different parameters. But for the all three plots We have same temperature T=4K . Then how can I add this information in the figure?

I am not interested to write it in the Caption. I want it on the figure itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667502/matplotlib-add-labels-aligned-to-bottom-of-axis/14667686#14667686 example with nifty use of blended transforms.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what sort of labeling you want?  In almost all imaginable cases, the answer is yes, you can add it, but knowing exactly what you want added would make answering a lot easier.

Answer (score 12):

**[figtext](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext)** would work well.

The advantage of `figtext` over `text` and `annotate` is that `figtext` defaults to using the figure coordinates, whereas the others default to using the coordinates of the axes (and therefore "T=4K" would move around if your axes are different between the different plots).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(0, .01)
plt.figtext(.8, .8, "T = 4K")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you can tell both `annotate` and `text` to use figure units (or a [mix](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations))

Comment: @tcaswell: Yes, but the important aspect of my answer is to point out that OP probably wants figure coordinates (which none of the other answers mention), not the various ways to get there.  And `figtext` is the obvious way to get there, not `text` with a transform.

Comment: I like your edit better.  I would have assumed that the OP wanted axes units though, so you don't have to fix it up if you do sub-plots or change the tick label size ect.

Comment: @tcaswell: good point.  It seems important perceptually (and aesthetically preferable) to have the 4K in the same absolute location of each subplot.  If you write up a simple way to do this, I think it would be the best answer thus far.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a demonstration of using `annotate`.  Check out [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo2.html) for different styles of annotation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0,4,100)

plt.plot(x,2*x)
plt.plot(x,x**2)
plt.plot(x,np.sqrt(8*x))

ax.annotate('T = 4K', xy=(2,4), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-100,60), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='fancy',fc='0.6',
                            connectionstyle="angle3,angleA=0,angleB=-90"))

plt.show()
raw_input()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[`figtext`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext) can make annotations at the bootom of multiple subplots figure like a comment independent of figures so you can make additional comments or remarks all in one picture. I was looking for this too. Thank you guys! :-)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.suptitle("SOME TITLE HERE")
#FIRST SUBPLOT
plt.subplot(311)
plt.ylabel(r"$a [m/s^2]$") # YOU CAN USE LaTeX TYPESETTING IN PYPLOT STRINGS!
plt.xlabel("time [s]")
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(some_data)
# SECOND SUBPLOT
plt.subplot(312)
...
# THIRD SUBPLOT
plt.subplot(313)
...
# BOTTOM LABEL
plt.figtext(0.5, 0, "SOME LABEL BELOW ALL SUBPLOTS", ha="center", fontsize=7, bbox={"facecolor":"orange", "alpha":0.5, "pad":5})
# DRAW THE PLOT
plt.show()
```

Notre `ha=center` will center the string if `x=0.5`. You can also use `fontsize` and `bbox` parameters to change appearance of the string and its area.

Comment: FIGTEXT is the essential answer. someone who asks this question will understand as well as find the library reference. there is also an explanation why this is the answer, so it is not "link-only answer" man.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure what you mean, but you can add text to the plot with the `text()` method.

[Plot text in matplotlib pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a grey horizontal zone around the T=4K zone

If you look at `axhspan(ymin, ymax, xmin=0, xmax=1, **kwargs)` in the [matplotlib documentation for axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html), you can make things like that:

[image: horizontal and vertical zones]